# QTabwidget click tab event C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am new in QT 4 C++ .I have QT 4 form with QTabwidget like in th picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlRYa.png)

I want to disply on console the string "aa" by selecting tab on clicking it.

Here is my newForm.h

```
#ifndef _NEWFORM_H
#define _NEWFORM_H

#include "qwidget.h"
#include "ui_newForm.h"
       
class newForm : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    newForm();
    virtual ~newForm();
private:
    Ui::newForm widget;
};

#endif /* _NEWFORM_H */
_________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "newForm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    newForm *a = new newForm();
    a->show();
    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

Here is my newForm.cpp

```
#include "newForm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

newForm::newForm() {
    connect(widget.tabWidget, SIGNAL(stateChanged()), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)));
    widget.setupUi(this);    
}

newForm::~newForm() {
}
void newForm::onTabChanged(int ){       
    qDebug()<<"aa"<<"\n";       
}
```

On selecting new tab it is not displaying "aa"?How to qDebug() "aa" on console?

Comment: Sorry, but you've already posted this question ([now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391337/qtabwidget-click-tab-event-c)) and the same comments apply.  What is the type of widget.tabWidget? Does it actually point to something that has a stateChanged signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you using Qt 4 in 2022?
Next thing use `currentIndexChanged(int)` istead of `stateChanged()`.
Did you also noticed that `stateChanged()` doesnt pass an interger which is needed for `onTabChanged(int)`.
You also connected `widget.tabWidget` which isn't initilized yet.

This code might work:

newForm.h

```cpp
#ifndef _NEWFORM_H
#define _NEWFORM_H

#include "qwidget.h"

namespace Ui { class newForm; };

       
class newForm : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    newForm();
    ~newForm();

private:
    Ui::newForm *widget;
};

#endif /* _NEWFORM_H */
```

newForm.cpp

```cpp
#include "newForm.h"
#include "ui_newForm.h"

#include <QDebug>


newForm::newForm() 
    : widget(new Ui::newForm)
{
    widget->setupUi(this);

    connect(widget->tabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)));
}

void newForm::onTabChanged(int ){       
    qDebug() << "aa";       
}

newForm::~newForm() {
    delete widget;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "newForm.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    newForm a;
    a.show();
    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: it is giving this error : `QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::currentIndexChanged(int) to newForm::onTabChanged(int)`.....How i can get required output "aa" on clicking tab ?

Comment: `Object::connect: No such signal QTabWidget::currentIndexChanged(int) in newForm.cpp:25
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'tabWidget')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'newForm')`

Comment: `SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int))` should be [`SIGNAL(currentChanged(int))`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop).